# Angular config block setting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having this problem with initializing Facebook and other providers, is it possible to execute this code somehow not on an application start but when user comes to the page where I want to use it? I will be getting APP_ID from API call and I dont want to load data required on page x on homepage.

```
.config(function(FacebookProvider) {
 // Set your appId through the setAppId method or
 // use the shortcut in the initialize method directly.
 FacebookProvider.init('YOUR_APP_ID');
```

})

Comment: I think `.run() block` on specific controller will help you.

Comment: "but when user comes to the page where I want to use it" => just put the code in the controller of the page... It is made for that.

Comment: Pierre -  the problem is I cant use FacebookProvider in controller

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to use a **service** as it is a singleton and won't be initialised multiple times.

> Add a **facebook** service like this -

```
app.service('facebook', function(FacebookProvider) {
  this.init: function(){
     FacebookProvider.init('YOUR_APP_ID');
  }
});
```

> Then you can **inject** the *facebook* and call the **init** method like this -

```
app.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, fb) {
  fb.init();
});
```

Hope this helped.

**UPDATE**

> Apparently **Providers** can't be injected into services as they can only be accessed through the .config() block

**Workaround**

> We can use the *$injector* object -

```
app.service('fb', function($injector) {
  this.init: function(){
     var FacebookProvider = $injector.get('FacebookProvider');
     FacebookProvider.init('YOUR_APP_ID');
  }
});
```

Comment: I cant inject FacebookProvider into service... Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: FacebookProviderProvider <- FacebookProvider

Comment: can you please update your question with your updated code that you're using?

Comment: I created service exactly as you suggested but FacebookProvider can be used only in config i guess - have a look at this https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook

Comment: I tried that, getting the same error when injector tries to get FacebookProvider.. :-(

Comment: @Gatekeeper I think the problem is with the service's name... Try changing it to something *other than* **facebook**.. for example *fb*

Comment: no, sadly the "$injector.get('FacebookProvider');" stil throwing error

Answer (score 0):

@atefth options is good ,but you can also do it in route resolve.